# añadir un evento click a unbotón con javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema muy simple que no sé por qué está ocurriendo.
Tengo un botón al que le quiero añadir un evento click para que cuando haga click, me salte un alert. El problema es que el alert salta en cuanto abro la página y cuando le doy al botón, no hace nada. El código está aparentemente bien y me estoy volviendo loco...

```
<a href="#" id="next">&#10095;</a>

<script>
    const botonNext = document.querySelector('#next');

    eventListeners();

    function eventListeners() {
        if (botonNext) {
            botonNext.addEventListener('click', alert("hola"));
        }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te hacía falta colocar el "alert" dentro de una función.

```js
    const botonNext = document.querySelector('#next');

    eventListeners();

    function eventListeners() {
        if (botonNext) {
            botonNext.addEventListener('click', function(){
              alert("hola")
            });
        }

    }
```

```html
<a href="#" id="next">&#10095;</a>
```

Comment: Perfecto!!! ya funuciona. Muchísimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que en el segundo argumento de un `EventListener` debe ir una función, tu lo que estás haciendo allí es la ejecutando una función, es por eso que el alert salta de una vez al cargar la página.

Lo que tienes que hacer es envolver la ejecución del alert en una función.

```
const botonNext = document.querySelector('#next');

eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {
    if (botonNext) {
        botonNext.addEventListener('click', function(){
          alert("hola")
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfecto!!! ya funuciona. Muchísimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

También puedes hacerlo mediante una función de flecha:

```
function eventListeners() {
    if (botonNext) {
        botonNext.addEventListener('click', () => alert("hola"));
    }
}
```